# Purging Process halts after running 10 delete queries

Tags: java, oracle

I have a requirements  to create a purging program using Java to purge record from database. Records will be purged from each tables before certain date (depending on defined in property file).

I have created program and decided all tables in to certain functions (NOT database function, but Java functions user defined) so that it can handles interdependent tables together. This program runs fine till 10 queries (first 4 functions) but halts at 5 the function of sequence defined.

In this case it does not throw any errors / exception. Looks to be keep executing it.

I have created Java functions like below.

```
purgeDatabaseOperations.purgeClsOfSvcHistTable(date);
purgeDatabaseOperations.purgeWmUiScrnChgLgTable(date);
```

each function may have more then 1 delete queries, each queries is getting added to array list and passed to database purging to be actually purging from database using stmt.executeBatch() function.

For now as i am doing testing, i am not explicitly committing database and defined connection.setAutoCommit(false) in my code so it will NOT commit to database.

**Do anyone really know what could be the cause of program to get halts? Where do i need to start digging.** I have tried reordering functions but did not help.

Regards,
Jay Shukla

Comment: Finally this process got aborted with following exception...

Comment: 2016-01-13 12:25:22 DEBUG OracleUtil:executeBatch:84 - SQL Exception - executeBatch()...Exiting
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: error occurred during batching: No more data to read from socket

Comment: It sounds like your connection may have timed out.